# Play framework with out scala UI template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am coming from the Java EE world. New to scala and Play. Looking at some sample applications. I see scala code in html files. I am able to understand the framework but I could not get scala.html files. Do I need to learn scala to use Play framework. Any work around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java version of Play!](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaHome) without any scala skills. If you don't want to use scala.html templates you can get some module providing Java templates for Play20. Modules list can be found [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Modules).

Some examples with samples:

- [Groovy Template Engine for Play Framework 2.0](https://github.com/mbknor/gt-engine-play2)
- [A full feaured Java-based template engine for Play2](https://github.com/branaway/japid42)

Comment: Hi Andrey, Thank you for the reply. I gone through different modules I didn't find any. Could you please help me out with specific module

Comment: @user1477037, added some examples to my answer